# Difference FragmentPagerAdapter and PagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I read the documentation for android pageadapter and fragmentpageadapter and I didn't see any difference. I mean one is a fragment and one isn't but.. is that all? I don't have really much experience with fragments so maybe thats why I don't notice any difference.
So whats the difference if I use a FragmentPagerAdapter or a PagerAdapter??

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The difference is that you can use Fragments inside a `FragmentPageAdapter`. If you want to have fragments that are going to be used in other parts of your code this is your Adapter.
Otherwise if you only want to have code that isn't going to be reused, you can use `PagerAdapter`.

Comment: so each page in the normal pageradapter is created again and again when you swipe your finger?? or it reuses the view? or you mean that code that isnt going to be reused in other classes? thanks in advance

Comment: No, I had to mean that when you use fragment, normally you are going to use this fragments in more than one single activity. The fragments are linked to the activity which contains them, so the reusability of view in this case is the same than in a viewPager. In the post I was talking about reusability regarding to functionality, not regarding to view. Sorry for not properly explain

Comment: @jegumi What do you mean 'isn't going to be reuse'?

Comment: that just use that fragment on one place on your app (one activity for example)

Answer (score 9):

Implementation of PagerAdapter that uses a Fragment to manage each page. But I highly recommend  to use FragmentStatePagerAdapter class also handles saving and restoring of fragment's state.

***FragmentStatePagerAdapter version of the pager is more useful when there are a large number of pages, working more like a list view. When pages are not visible to the user, their entire fragment may be destroyed, only keeping the saved state of that fragment. This allows the pager to hold on to much less memory associated with each visited page as compared to FragmentPagerAdapter at the cost of potentially more overhead when switching between pages.***

When using FragmentPagerAdapter the host ViewPager must have a valid ID set.

Subclasses only need to implement getItem(int) and getCount() to have a working adapter.

Here is an example [implementation of a FragmentStatePagerAdapter pager containing fragments of lists](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html)